# Google Chrome browser turns white

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

My google Chrome browser PAGE turns white when I browser some sites like Instagram.. I can't notice the relationship of those sites, however I have to reload the website. Sometimes the pages blinks when this problem occurs.

I have unchecked Hardware acceleration option in Chrome settings. This happens to both Chrome and Chromium. This does not happen when I use Firefox. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, a screenshot, might provide the required clarification.

Comment: Should I provide a totally white screenshot? OK then I will add it.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, but I did not think my comment as sarcastic, I said that because I did not think that screenshot will help as I have mentioned that MY CHROME BROWSER TURNS WHITE.. anyway Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: Is your Chrome Updated? If not then plz do and plz Try browsing in an incognito window. Go to wrench icon > select New incognito window.  If this is also not successful then I'll search in details about your query.

Comment: Thank you for coming to help me. My Chromium version is Version 51.0.2704.79 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) Google Chrome version is Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit) I also tried incognito mode and the result is the same.

Comment: Please try disabling and closing your antivirus and firewall temporarily..

Comment: Thank you. I face this problem on Ubuntu. So no antivirus installed. I have both WIndows and Ubuntu installed but no problem on Windows 10.

Comment: (This Issue may be triggered by a corrupted user profile or a misbehaving extension)---> Please create a new Chrome user (Wrench > Settings > Users > Add new user), and in the new window associated with this user, visit the webpages that were not loading before. If it loads then it means that your profile has been corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. Is there any way to fix a corrupted user profile and how that corrupting happens?